# When does an NHL game actually start?

Tags: toronto, sports-events, north-america

Planning to see an NHL game in Toronto. What does the posted time indicate? Is it when pregame ceremonies (player presentations, national anthems etc) start or is when the actual game is supposed to take place?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Travel as described in the Help page: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @David I disagree, there are [lots of questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports-events?tab=Newest) with this tag

Comment: @Daniil None of those address the sole question asked here. They all, IMO, are indeed arguably related to "Travel." This isn't. The exact same question could be asked by a resident of Toronto.

Comment: The question you refer have a similar situation "where to watch a sport event" rather than when a event starts so I agree with David.

Comment: To answer the OP, if the posted time is at 7:00 ET, then the game will begin approximately 7:00-7:05.  The pregame ceremonies/anthem(s) will be finishing at the posted start time.

Comment: Reopening as this is a perfectly valid travel question.

Comment: Just watching tonight's Minnesota at Nashville game.  It was posted to start at 8:00 and the puck actually dropped at 8:15, but this may not be representative - it's the first game of the season and there were extra ceremonies.

Comment: So, when do the ceremonies typically start?

Answer (score 5):

For all sports events in general, the start time is the start of the final, official pre-game shenanigans which (depending on if it's the playoffs or something special) is close to the actual game start time.

They will often have up to an hour of other stuff beforehand - random awards, kids brought out to do something,  remote control blimps dropping buffalo wing coupons on you, whatever.  But as most pro sports are televised, the start time is effectively "when the cameras start rolling", which may involve a national anthem and coin flip or similar but that should only take 5-15 minutes under normal condition before the game itself commences.

Heh, you're apparently not the only high maintenance hockey watcher out there - [here's an actual schedule from the Ottawa Senators](https://www.nhl.com/senators/fans/game-set-up-and-production) indicating general buzzer time vs start time and surrounding times (note it depends on number of national anthems). It is apparently a NHL standard.